# Do I need to remove a laundry standpipe trap before using the pipes for a sink?

Tags: plumbing, kitchens, sink, p-trap

We are renovating our basement and adding a kitchenette. The kitchenette space used to be where the washer and dryer were, as you can tell by the water, lines and drain stand pipe.

We plan on using the existing waterlines and drain for the kitchenette sink and I didn’t know if I needed to remove the old trap for the stand pipe. The sink will have its own trap, so I didn’t know if having 2 in the same drain line is bad, or if it’ll be ok.

Thanks for your patience and friendly feedback.

[image]

Comment: Plus one for cutting a hole big enough to work in, right off the bat (*That's the drywaller's problem* - but *big hole, little hole*; it's all the same to them). Cabinet will need a hole cut for an access panel for that clean out. And when you do the water lines, bring them down to a tee, the outlets of which go to shutoffs, and the other (cross) end of the tee gets two elbows to bring it back up vertical for water hammers. (direction of flow to be preserved *through* the tee to the hammers; the change in direction is where the valve goes).

Answer (score 2):

Having 2 traps can cause problems.

Since it is easy to access, cut it out and use the normal p-trap you would for under the sink.

Answer (score 2):

You do. Redundant traps are generally disallowed by code and are a maintenance concern.

Mostly, though, you need to reduce that 2" pipe to 1-1/2" for your sink anyway. Cut it at the horizontal run, reduce it, and extend to add a trap adapter at the appropriate height. Better to do it in the wall than have extra fittings protruding into the cabinet.

Also be aware that you may not meet vent code with what's there. You need the sink to be vented within 42" for 1-1/2" pipe. (60" for 2" pipe, but I'm not sure how that works when you're reducing for the sink.)

Comment: *may not meet vent code* - that's only one of the reasons I'd keep it in 2" for as long as possible, which would leave a 2" tee sticking up for the vent, and put a reducing bushing on its outlet for 1-1/2". - You get anywhere from twice to three times the capacity on a 2" instead of a 1-1/2". Math is for chumps. Pipe is cheap. The only thing I do with 1-1/2" is cut less than 8" takeoffs for stubbing a drain out a wall.

Comment: I thought about that, too, but I'm not sure how to calculate legal trap arm for a mixed size scenario. 1-1/2" pipe is extremely unlikely to clog from a vanity sink, though, assuming proper slope.